# Floating asides to each side of a section?

Tags: html, css, css-float, floating

I have two aside tags. One aside tag needs to be floated to the right, the other needs to be floated the left. They're both on the correct sides but the section won't let the asides go next to it, they are still below it.

Here's the html:
http://pastebin.com/BHtdYZfD

Here's the css:
http://pastebin.com/jhfLNNfS

Maybe, I left something out in the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You certainly left something out of the question ... a jsFiddle, which would be infinitely more helpful than pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: just change the HTML-code a little bit like this:

```
        <header>
                <img src="town_hall_logo.gif" alt="Town Hall logo" height="80">
                <hgroup>
                        <h1>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</h1>
                        <h2>Celebrating our <span class="shadow">75<sup>th</sup></span> Year</h2>
                </hgroup>
        </header>

        <aside class="aside2">
                <h1>Event change for November 16</h1>
                <p>SJV Town Hall is pleased to announce the addition of award-winning author Andrew Ross Sorkin.
                The appearance of previously scheduled speaker, Greg Mortenson, has been postponed.</p>
        </aside>
        <aside>
                <h1 id="speakers">2011-2012 Speakers</h1>
                <h2>October 19, 2011<br><a href="nopage.html">Jeffrey Toobin</a></h2>
                <img src="toobin75.jpg" alt="Jeffrey Toobin photo">
                <h2>November 16, 2011<br><a href="nopage.html">Andrew Ross Sorkin</a></h2>
                <img src="sorkin75.jpg" alt="Andrew Ross Sorkin photo">
                <h2>January 18, 2012<br><a href="nopage.html">Amy Chua</a></h2>
                <img src="chua75.jpg" alt="Amy Chua photo">
                <h2>February 15, 2012<br><a href="nopage.html">Scott Sampson</a></h2>
                <img src="sampson75.jpg" alt="Scott Sampson">
        </aside>
        <section>
                <h1>Our Mission</h1>
                <p>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall is a non-profit organization that is run by an all-volunteer board of directors. Our mission is to bring nationally and internationally renowned, thought-provoking speakers who inform, educate, and entertain our audience! As one or our members told us:</p>
                <blockquote>“Each year I give a ticket package to each of our family members. I think of it as the gift of knowledge...and that is priceless.”</blockquote>
                <h1>Speaker of the Month</h1>
                <article>
                        <h1>Fossil Threads in the Web of Life</h1>
                        <img src="sampson_dinosaur.jpg" alt="Scott Sampson with Dinosaur">
                        <h2>February 15, 2012<br>Scott Sampson</h2>
                        <p>What's 75 million years old and brand spanking new? A teenage Utahceratops! Come to the Saroyan, armed with your best dinosaur roar, when Scott Sampson, Research Curator at the Utah Museum of Natural History, steps to the podium. Sampson's research has focused on the ecology and evolution of late Cretaceous dinosaurs and he has conducted fieldwork in a number of countries in Africa.</p>
                        <p><a href="nopage.html">Read more.</a>&nbsp;<b>Or meet us there!</b></p>
                </article>
                <h1>Our Ticket Packages</h1>
                <ul>
                        <li>Season Package: $95</li>
                        <li>Patron Package: $200</li>
                        <li>Single Speaker: $25</li>
                </ul>
        </section><footer>
                <p>© 2012, San Joaquin Valley Town Hall, Fresno, CA 93755</p>
        </footer>







</body>
```

and then remove those CSS rules in section:

```
clear: left;
clear: both;
```